# Simplifying PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to ask you a question.
For example I have an equation:
$$u_{tt}-7u_{xx}-u_{x}=0 $$
To solve it I must first simplify it, right? I mean I must remove $u_x$. I suppose, that I must use next formulas:
$$ u_{x} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\lambda V + V_{x})$$
$$u_{xx} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\lambda^{2} V + 2\lambda V_{x} + V_{xx})$$
$$u_{tt} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\mu^{2} V + 2\mu V_{t} + V_{tt}) $$
Am I right?
Will the primary conditions or\and boundary conditions change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you substitute $e^{\lambda x+\mu t}V(x,t)$ for $u(x,t)$ in your PDE and get rid of the exponential, you find:
$$V_{tt} -7\ V_{xx}-(14\lambda +1)\ V_x +2\mu\ V_t+(\mu^2-7\lambda^2-\lambda)\ V=0\; ;$$
if you want to get rid of $V_t$ and $V_x$ you have to choose $\lambda ,\mu$ s.t.:
$$14\lambda +1=0\quad \text{and} \quad 2\mu=0\; ,$$
hence $\lambda=-1/14$ and $\mu=0$, so that:
$$u(x,t)=e^{-x/14}\ V(x,t)$$
and your PDE becomes:
$$V_{tt}-7\ V_{xx}+\frac{1}{28}\ V=0\; .$$

Now, it seems that you have the following IC/BC:
$$\tag{IC} \begin{cases}u(x,0) = x - x^2 \\ u_t(x,0) = 0 \end{cases}$$
$$\tag{BC} \begin{cases}u(0,t) = 0 \\ u(1,t) = \sin(\pi t / 2)\end{cases}$$
and $t_{last} = 2$; such conditions in terms of $V$ read:
$$\begin{cases} V(x,0) = e^{x/14}\ x\ (1 - x) & \text{, in } [0,1]\\ V_t(x,0) = 0 & \text{, in } [0,1]\end{cases} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \begin{cases} V(0,t) = 0 &\text{, in } [0,2]\\ V(1,t) = e^{1/14}\ \sin(\pi t / 2)&\text{, in } [0,2].\end{cases}$$

I have to say that, even if your substitution simplifies the PDE (for it cancels the term with the first derivative), it complicates the ICs; therefore that substitution doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Yes yes yes. My answer is 98% same as yours) <br> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94292/changing-ic-and-bc-after-simplification   <br> But you give me acknowledgment, that my thoughts were right.... Fuf... It's good. Thank you very much. Because I was on 3-4 forums and 2 days no one has helped me. <br> P.S.: Is there any way to contact with you?

Comment: "PDE (for it cancels the term with the first derivative), it complicates the ICs" Professor said to do this. 4 days ago I tried did this without substitution and I had got very big and complicated koefficients etc. P.S.: I don't know how to complete solve this equation, I tried to do this last 3-4 days and I will trying to do this all the night today. Hopefully, that I'll the right answer for morning )

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those anzats, the equation is already amenable to a separation of variables via $u(t,x)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$. This substitution will give

$$
X(x)\cdot T''(t)- 7X''(x)\cdot T(t) - X'(x)\cdot T(t) = 0
$$
$$
X(x)\cdot T''(t)- (7X''(x) + X'(x))T(t)=0
$$
$$
\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{7X''(x) + X'(x)}{X(x)}=k,\hspace{5mm}k\in\mathbb{R}
$$

Solve these single variable DE's with the help of your original BC/IC's.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that, but I think it's not a good idea. Because I have inhomogeneous BC/IC's, without simplifying I will have a very complicated which I will not be able so solve (

Comment: @ScienceSE: If the problem lies in the specific BC/IC you are interested in, it seems rather odd that these are not even *mentioned* in your question. How to *avoid* making people able to answer one's question...

Comment: Sorry. I don't know english perfectly to describe all) I was in a consult-lesson today, the teacher said to do simplification first, so I'll try to do this. Actually sometimes I start to panic and nervous, when I don't know how to do somethink in mathematics, physics.. Because these things makes a great influence on my life... It would be nice if I knew a person, who knows this things good and have, for example, skype or something more..