# Changing IC and BC after simplification

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplifying PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94086/simplifying-pde)

I have a pde:

$$u_{tt}-7u_{xx}-u_{x}=0$$

IC:

$$u(x,0) = x - x^2 $$
$$u_t(x,0) = 0$$

BC:

$$u(0,t) = 0 $$
$$u(L,t) = \sin(\pi t / 2)$$

$$t_\mathrm{last} = 2$$
$$L = 1$$

I was simplifying it using next formulas:

$$u(x,t)=e^{\lambda x + \mu t}\ V(x,t) $$
$$u_{x} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\lambda V + V_{x})$$
$$u_{xx} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\lambda^{2} V + 2\lambda V_{x} + V_{xx})$$
$$u_{tt} = e^{\lambda x + \mu t}(\mu^{2} V + 2\mu V_{t} + V_{tt})$$

After that I've got:
$$V_{tt}-7V_{xx}-\frac{3}{28}V=0 $$
Help please: IC and BC must change, but how to change them? What will be new IC\BC?

Comment: A little. In this topic I've added results, which I've got.

Comment: The problem has just solved in previous topic. Thanks for Pacciu.